Filtering SQL Data
How do you write a query for data filtering using the parch and posey DB  for the following -
i) Retrieve the order id and the quantity ordered of only standard paper.
ii) Identify the top 10 total orders by paper quantity ordered
iii) Identify large total orders that are greater than 2000 pieces
I tried the following and i got errors.

SELECT order_id, quantity_ordered
FROM orders
WHERE paper_type = 'standard paper'

SELECT order_id, SUM(quantity_ordered) as total_quantity
FROM orders
GROUP BY order_id
ORDER BY total_quantity DESC
LIMIT 10

SELECT order_id, SUM(quantity_ordered) as total_quantity
FROM orders
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING total_quantity > 2000



i got errors And how should we know what errors you got? Please share some information if you want help. (in plain text, as an update of your question)

Your syntax is fine, but you need to check your variable names. You don't say where you got the sample Parch and Posey dataset, but those variable names don't match the variables found, for example, here: https://github.com/Chisomnwa/SQL-for-Data-Analysis---Parch-and-Posey/blob/main/Parcn%20and%20Posey%20Schema.png
